# Idexing pdf files using PDF-Paragraph converter

Tags: watson-explorer

When i index pdf files and using PDF-Paragraph converter WEX put a default title on all documents the (title). How can i modify this title using xpath?
On the search page all documents has the same title.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg22009088

check it we need to create a new custom java converter for your reqirement